# how use canvg for convert svg of bubble chart to png?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, bubble-chart, canvg

how i can use canvg library to convert bubble chart to png?
i draw a bubble chart with highcharts library.
when i use canvg and save to png i see a empty png.

```
var svg = new Highcharts().getSVG()
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvg(canvas, svg);
```

[image: empty Image]

Comment: Have you consider exporting Highcharts charts to png using exporting.js module? http://jsfiddle.net/tjtcxLx9/1/

Comment: thank you for answer. solved